# Is it okay for a Muslim to participate in the mandatory government pension and health insurance in Japan?

Tags: halal-haram, insurance

In Japan, you have to participate in the mandatory government pension. The policy works as follows:

1. Every month government takes out a certain amount from your salary. Your contributor also contributes the same amount.
2. When you reach 60 years old you get a fixed monthly amount as a pension from the government. This pension is provided until you die.
3. After you die, your spouse gets 3/4th of the amount until he/she dies.

The Japanese government also has mandatory health insurance that works as follows:

1. Every month government takes a certain amount from your salary. Your employer also contributes the same amount.
2. For any kind of medical expense you pay 30%(with a maximum cap) and the government pays the rest.
3. Your spouse and children are also covered.

Now I am not currently in Japan but if I accept an offer from a Japanese company I have to move to Japan and accept this pension and other insurance policies.
Is it okay for me to accept this?

#### Edit:

Concerns: The fund is managed by the government and we are not sure how they manage it. Maybe they are investing the fund in the haram businesses. Should we be concerned about how the government is managing the fund?

Comment: Can you explain more about why you think it's a problem? In fact, it is a contract where the parties have obligations. For this reason, we can check it.

Comment: The fund is managed by the government and we are not sure how they manage it. Maybe they are investing the fund in the haram businesses. Should we be concerned about how the government is managing the fund?

Comment: If you are not sure that it is invested in a haram business, then it is permissible to use that money. [https://www.makarem.ir/main.aspx?typeinfo=21&lid=0&catid=46709]